# Laravel vapor returns message:null when click on browser back button

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I recently started using Laravel vapor as my server and I've realized that when I click on the browser back (history) button, I get this weird message:

[Image of the returned message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enMH4.png)

Did anyone have this issue?

I have no idea which part of the code to share with you that would be relevant for this issue since I didn't find any similar problem on the internet.

If you need something, comment and I will edit the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to you having a route with the same path for displaying and getting JSON data. The browser may cache the JSON version and show that when hitting the back button.

If you could share the relevant routes that match, I can go into more detail.

Comment: Could this issue be triggered by route change on the vapor? Recently I bought a new domain and connected DNS. Would you like vapor.yml or laravel routes?

Comment: No, this is an application error and not specific to Vapor. Any routing you have that handles the URL triggering the issue.

Comment: Hmm... nothing unusual... I mean on local everything is fine.